# How to fit Plotly plot size dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, css, plot, plotly

Previously I asked a question how to fit Bokeh plot size dynamically and I got a solution from HYRY.

[How to fit bokeh plot size dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879674/how-to-fit-bokeh-plot-size-dynamically)

Now I would like the same question for the Plotly plot.

Similarly to HYRY's method, I could achieve the same effect using Plotly.relayout javascript function:

```
TweenMax.to($("#div2"), 0.5, {height:800, onUpdate:function(){Plotly.relayout("493d6ad0-561e-49b1-9c37-f9c427ba7880", {width:1800, height:800});}});
```

Thanks again to HYRY.

What's inconvenient for Plotly case, I could not find a way to specify plot id on my own. In Bokeh, we can supply id via python function instead of randomly generated id:

```
blue = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_both', tools='pan', id="blue_fig")
```

Would there be any good way?